# Changing axes labels when creating automated diagrams with map() loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have a dataset containing 15 explanatory an 13 response variables. I want to create a diagram with a group of boxplots for each combination of these variables.
I was able to create all the 195 diagrams with the help of this [tutorial](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/).

This is my code for the automated boxplots:

```
resp =names(dataframe)[3:15]
expl =names(dataframe)[16:30]

resp =set_names(resp)
resp
expl =set_names(expl)
expl

box_fun=function(x,y){
  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x= .data[[x]], y= .data[[y]], fill=Gewaesser))+
    geom_boxplot()+
}

all_plots=map(resp, function(resp){
  map(expl, function(expl){
    box_fun(x=expl, y=resp)
  })
})
 
all_plots
```

Now I want to change the axes labels and the title is different for each variable. I created a vector of names for each axis, and tried incoperating them into my plotting function:

```
xlab=c("x", "y", "z")
ylab=c("1", "2", "3")

box_fun=function(x,y,xlab,ylab) {
  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x= .data[[x]], y= .data[[y]], fill=Gewaesser))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    labs(x=xlab, y=ylab)}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make all the plots now.
I've tried `all_plots=pmap(list(expl, resp, xlab, ylab))` but get the error '! Can't recycle `.l[[1]]` (size 15) to match `.l[[2]]` (size 13).'

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`pmap` requires a list of elements of equal length, whereas all of your vectors (`expl`, ...) have a different length.

Instead you could use e.g. `expand_grid(expl, resp)`  to create a dataframe of the combos of variables you want to plot. Then add the axes labels for each combo as new columns.

Afterwards you could use `pmap` to loop over the rows of this dataset.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

expl <- names(mtcars[c("cyl", "am", "gear")])
resp <- names(mtcars[c("mpg", "disp", "hp")])

names(resp) <- resp
names(expl) <- expl

dat <- tidyr::expand_grid(x = expl, y = resp)
dat$xlab <- rep(c("x", "y", "z"), each = 3)
dat$ylab <- rep(c("1", "2", "3"), 3)

box_fun <- function(x, y, xlab, ylab) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], fill = factor(vs))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(x = xlab, y = ylab)
}

all_plots <- pmap(dat, box_fun)

all_plots[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it this way and it worked :)